# Increasing the Maximum Shank Dia

Tags: tools, drill, powertools, chuck

There is a device in my head that I know must exist, but I can't seem to find it.

I own a drill. Kinda small. It has a small chuck so the shank dia of the drill bits that I can use is limited. Is there a way around this limitation?

I figure there must be a device that is basically a large chuck connected to a thin shank which can fit in the chuck of my drill, effectively allowing me to use drill bits with greater dias.

*Links to where I can purchase this imaginary device would be appreciated.*

Comment: All I could find was hex shanked drill chucks . they called them " Chuck converter" but I have seen a 3/8 shaft on a 1/2" Chuck but did not see one with a quick search, the hex version would probably work fine as it would not slip.

Comment: The chuck size is typically based on the power of the motor in the drill.  You can use large bits with a reduced shank to fit the chuck, but you risk destroying your drill trying to use bits larger than the drill is designed to handle.

Answer (score 2):

There are bits referred to as Silver and Deming bits.  They have a smaller shank than the actual bit diameter and are available at home centers or on line. They come in a traditional twist drill configuration, so they can be used for drilling metal. If you are working with wood then "paddle" or "spade" bits will work also. You have to use caution when drilling holes of a larger diameter than the drill was designed. The drill may not have the secondary handle needed to control the torque. The speed of a single speed drill may be too high to control the bit. You may also overload and over heat the motor to the point of failure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of the device you are imagining but they do make drill bits with reduced shank diameter which should accomplish what you're trying to do. 
[Like this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj2nPPfvcfdAhVM5YMKHQvvDbgQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FDrill-America-DWDRSD-Reduced-12-50mm%2Fdp%2FB01DALT2TA&psig=AOvVaw3PBKh7Xx68S8xrmQtX_7wb&ust=1537460739008795) Also you may be able to remove the chuck on your drill and replace it with a larger one.